# Proof on infimum and supremum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

[image]

Sorry for the poor photo quality. Can someone please tell me does my proof of this question valid or not?

Comment: What is "by definition $-a$ has a greatest lower bound" in fourth row of an answer? What a definition? What do you mean by telling "number has a lower bound"?

Comment: @sas By definition of infimum. I want to say that because -a has an infimum, so the infimum of -a has to greater then all other lower bound (i.e -sup(A) )

Comment: What is an "infimum of $-a$"?  $-a$ is a number.  A number can't have an infimum.  A set, however, can.

Comment: By definition of infimum infimum exists? It is not possible. Definition of a concept never could include statement of existence of this concept.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry that was a mistake. What if I add "for all -a is in the set -A" in my first line?

Comment: I don't see how that changes anything.  "$-a$" still can't have a "greatest lower bound".

Comment: @sas What if I add "for all -a is in the set -A" in my first line? Can I say there exists a infimum of -A if I add this statement?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Then could you please tell me how can I prove this question? Am I going a wrong direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "can I say"? You need to prove existence. Take your supremum which exists by condition and then prove by contradiction for example.

Comment: @sas Then how should I prove this question. I am so confused right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to prove the statement:

> Show that $-\sup(A)$ is a lower-bound for $-A$

For all $a \in A$, $a \leq \sup(A)$ (by definition).  Thus, $-a \geq -\sup(A)$.

Since $-a \geq \sup(A)$ for all $a \in A$, $-\sup(A)$ is a lower-bound for $-A$.

> Show that $- \sup(A)$ is the *greatest* lower-bound for $-A$.  That is, show that any other lower bound must be less than (or equal to) $-\sup(A)$.

Let $\alpha$ be an arbitrary lower bound of $-A$.  Then, for all $a \in A: -a \geq \alpha$.  Thus, for all $a \in A, a \leq -\alpha$.  Thus, $-\alpha$ is an upper bound for $A$.

However, $\sup(A)$ is the *least* upper bound of $A$.  Thus, $-\alpha \geq \sup(A)$.  Thus, $\alpha \leq -\sup(A)$.

Thus, every lower bound $\alpha$ of $-A$ satisifies $\alpha \leq -\sup(A)$.  Thus, $-\sup(A)$ is the *greatest* lower bound of $-A$.